# Is there a way to launch an EAR from maven?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, maven-3

Is there a maven module that allows you to launch an container and deploy an ear when you build a project? For example you can do this with Tomcat by using the Tomcat plugin for maven and running

```
mvn clean install tomcat:run
```

Comment: First an EAR does not belong to Tomcat cause Tomcat is a Servlet engine and not an application server so you should use JBoss, Glassfish etc. to use for EAR. If you use tomee this is a different story.

Comment: You can take a look at http://cargo.codehaus.org/Maven2+plugin which can be used to deploy an ear to JBoss etc. and there you can start an EAR.

Answer (score 1):

The [Cargo maven plugin](http://cargo.codehaus.org/Maven2+plugin) can be used to deploy EAR/WAR files to many different JavaEE containers.

An example:

```
mvn clean verify org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven2-plugin:run
-Dcargo.maven.containerId=tomcat7x
-Dcargo.maven.containerUrl=http://archive.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-7/v7.0.16/bin/apache-tomcat-7.0.16.zip
```

Automatically download Tomcat 7.0.16 from the specified URL (taking into account any proxy server setting you would have in Maven2/Maven3), instantiate the container, create a local configuration with your application and run it.

You can also configure it in your `pom.xml`...

Comment: That is correct. I just showed an example of usage - you need to use a container that support EARs like Jboss